# php mysql special character

Tags: php, mysql, html

My table looks like this-

```
province_id int(11)                  
province_title char(200) utf8_general_ci 
parent int(8) int(2)
```

I have inserted a lot of data direct from phpMyadmin (not from php page). but when i retrieve those data and show them in php page, then there are problems with special characters.

like-

```
Québec shows -  Qu�bec.
```

my html header looks like -

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
```

i think the problem might have happened while inserting the data. how can i convert those data in phpmyadmin? any help?

Comment: Do you really want to use char(200)?  The DBMS will use an awful lot of padding and waste disk space.  Why not use varchar instead?  Also, if you do change to varchar and if you're going to be searching on the parent column (e.g., when looking for children) you may want to put that before the varchar as fixed-width like ints columns should generally go first (makes searching quicker).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

seems like you're not using utf-8 *everywhere* so your data got messed up at some point. depending on what exactly you're doing, you'll have to change/add one or more of the following points (most likely it's the `SET CHARSET`/`mysql_set_charset` wich you forgot):

- tell MySQL to use utf-8. to do this, add this to your my.cnf:

  > ```
  > collation_server = utf8_unicode_ci
  > character_set_server = utf8
  > ```
- before interacting with mysql, send this two querys:

  > ```
  > SET NAMES 'utf8';
  > CHARSET 'utf8';
  > ```

  or, alternatively, let php do this after opening the connection:

  > ```
  > mysql_set_charset('utf8', $conn); // when using the mysql_-functions
  > mysqli::set_charset('utf8') // when using mysqli
  > ```
- set UTF-8 as the default charset for your database

  > ```
  > CREATE DATABASE `my_db` DEFAULT CHARACTER SET 'utf8';
  > ```
- do the same for tables:

  > ```
  > CREATE TABLE `my_table` (
  >   -- ...
  > ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
  > ```
- assuming the client is a browser, serve your content as utf-8 and the the correct header:

  > ```
  > header('Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
  > ```

  to be really sure the browser understands, add a meta-tag:

  > ```
  > <meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
  > ```
- and, last but not least, tell the browser to submit forms using utf-8

  > ```
  > <form accept-charset="utf-8" ...>
  > ```

Comment: +1 for a very complete answer.  As use of MySQL is discouraged, I suggest you add "or use mysqli::set_charset", too.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is probably the character set of your connection to MySQL.  See [mysql_set_charset](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-set-charset.php) or [mysqli::set_charset](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.set-charset.php)

Answer (score 0):

MySQL server is not configured to expect UTF-8 encoding by default from client.

So you have to open connection using

```
mysql_query("SET NAMES utf8");
```

If you are using PDO,

```
$options = array(
    PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => 'SET NAMES utf8',
); 

$dbh = new PDO($dsn, $username, $password, $options);
```

Answer (score 0):

If it looks ok when you see the data in phpmyadmin the problem may be with the text enconding of the file itself.

Use Eclipse (Edit » Set Encoding) or Notepad++ (Encoding) to confirm that you have the right encoding in the file.