# How do you insert strings containing foreign language special characters into SQL from PHP?

Tags: phpmyadmin, special-characters

For instance when I try to insert "Sebastián" into the database, it gets stored as "SebastiÃ¡n".

This is the test code which I am trying out:

```
<?php include 'database.php'; ?>

<?php
$name = "Sebastián";

$query = "INSERT INTO students (name) VALUES ('$name')";
$insert_row = $mysqli->query($query) or die($mysqli->error.__LINE__);

if($insert_row){
    echo "Insertion was successful";
}
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

I am using PhpMyAdmin and the setting of the server connection collation is illustrated in the below screenshot:

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [php mysql special character](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10721867/php-mysql-special-character)

Comment: You're using mysqli .. okay, good. Now use placeholders / parameterized queries. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174